# Spark RDD.saveAsTextFile writing empty files to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark

I'm trying to execute a map-reduce job using Spark 1.6 (`spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4.tgz`) that reads input from and writes output to S3.

The reads are working just fine with: `sc.textFile(s3n://bucket/path/to/file/file.gz)`

However, I'm having a bunch of trouble getting the writes to work. I'm using the same bucket to output the files: `outputRDD.saveAsTextFile(s3n://bucket/path/to/output/)`

When my input is extremely small (< 100 records), this seems to work fine. I'm seeing a `part-NNNNN` file written per partition with some of those files having 0 bytes and the rest being under 1 KB. Spot checking the non-empty files shows the correctly formatted map-reduce output. When I move to a slightly bigger input (~500 records), I'm seeing the same number of `part-NNNNN` files (my number of partitions are constant for these experiments), but each one is empty.

When I was experimenting with much bigger data sets (millions of records), my thought was that I was exceeding some S3 limits which was causing this problem. However, 500 records (which amounts to ~65 KB zipped) is still a trivially small amount of data that I would think Spark and S3 should handle easily.

I've tried using the S3 Block FileSystem instead of the S3 Native FileSystem as outlined [here](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3). But get the same results. I've turned on logging for my S3 bucket, but I can't seem to find a smoking gun there.

Has anyone else experienced this? Or can otherwise give me a clue as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: Typically empty output means that partitions are empty. Does the problem persist when you use `repartition(n)` before `saveAsTextFile`? If not you have your answer. If not please post a code which can be used to reproduce the problem. See [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes. That turned out to be the answer. I was filtering out all my records in my business logic. Which seems obvious now that I think about it. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was working on this too late at night. This morning, I took a step back and found a bug in my map-reduce which was effectively filtering out all the results.

Answer (score -3):

You should use `coalesce` before saveAsTextFile

from [spark programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html)

```
Decrease the number of partitions in the RDD to numPartitions. Useful
for running operations more efficiently after filtering down a large
dataset.
```

eg:

```
outputRDD.coalesce(100).saveAsTextFile(s3n://bucket/path/to/output/)
```

Comment: Thanks @Urban48, I actually was originally coalescing but had removed it to try to eliminate variables. The answer turns out to be that I was filtering out all my results before the `saveAsTextFile` was even run. Now that I've fixed that problem, I've added the `coalesce` back in and everything seems to be running smoothly.